# Woocommerce не экспортирует товары

Tags: woocommerce

Я использую стандартные средства экспорта woocommerce  6.8.0.
Если пробую экспортировать все товары, экспортируется только первая строчка (заголовок).
При этом раньше пробовал экспортировать и получалось.
В логе ошибок нет.
Что это может быть  ?

Answer (score 0):

Браузер Opera заглючила, видимо памяти не хватает. Незнаю в чем именно ошибка,
но в браузере  Edge, файл экспортируется и скачивается.